# What is the best practice when inserting a link on multiple Content Editors?

Tags: hyperlink

I'm new to SharePoint and just require one quick tip to perform some updates for my boss.

**Question**

I want to insert the same link to an external site to several Content Editors. What's the recommended way to do that so I can change the link in one central place and all the insertions will be adjusted?

**Elaboration**

I know [how to create a list of links](http://hosting.com/support/sharepoint3/links/). That list of links can be inserted on different pages and changing the original list will automatically update all the insertions.

I want the same effect for one single link. Can that be done?

**Example**

```
|---------------------------------------------------------|
|Content Editor 1                                         |
|                                                         |
| Some text and a LINK1 (= www.site.com/page1)            |
|---------------------------------------------------------|

|---------------------------------------------------------|
|Content Editor 2                                         |
|                                                         |
| Some other text and a LINK2 (= www.site.com/page1)      |
|---------------------------------------------------------|
```

Now, the link changes to www.site.com/pageX. So I have to go and update LINK1. I'll for sure miss LINK2 which will then be a broken link.

I would like to be able to change www.site.com/page1 to www.site.com/pageX at one central point and the both LINK1 and LINK2 will be pointing to the new URL.

Comment: Is the link pointing to a page within the same SharePoint web site ?

Comment: @MdMazzotti: No, it's pointing to a completely different website on the Internet.